# Need help with proving if function is necessarily surjective when domain is > than codomain.

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

Consider two finite sets $X$, $Y$ with $|X| > |Y|$. Now consider some function $f: X \to Y$. Is $f$ necessarily surjective? If so prove it, if not, give a counter example.

I know that this can be surjective, but I don't think it's necessarily onto. That being said, I can't think of a counterexample to prove this.

Comment: Sorry I just realized I had different variables in the function than the stated sets. That being said I've edited my question to reflect what I think.

Comment: Try looking at small sets. For example, if $X = \{1,2,3\}$ and $Y = \{1,2\}$, what are the possible functions $f : X \rightarrow Y$?

Comment: What about a constant function?

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Let $X$ be a set of $3$ elements, let $Y$ be a set of $2$ elements. Draw arrows between them. There are at most $8$ possiblies. You can enumerate this particular case and see if it is true for this particular setting.

Something to think about while you are working on constructing a counter example: Suppose each such function is equally likely to be picked, what is the probability that it will be a surjection?